# I keep getting an error when using webintent

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova, webintents

I am trying to open a webpage with cordova using this code:

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW,url: 'geo:0,0?q=' +            address}, 
function() {}, 
function() {alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent')}
)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: WebIntent is not defined
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Cordova 2.0` make sure you have the following entry in `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent" />
```

also the `WebIntent.java` file needs to be stored in:

```
src\com\borismus\webintent\
```

Finally make sure you include webintent.js after the cordova.js:

```
<script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/webintent.js"></script>
```